# How to apply maxWidth to TextField component from mui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to apply `maxWidth` to the `TextField` from material-ui but it seems like I can't.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const messages = [
    { id: 1, message: "short message" },
    {
      id: 2,
      message: " It comes with three variants: outlined."
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      message:
        "The TextField wrapper component is a complete form control including a label, input, and help text."
    }
  ];
  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" }
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
      style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}
    >
      {messages.map((e) => (
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          key={e.id}
          value={e.message}
          label="Outlined"
          variant="outlined"
          multiline={true}

          style={{ maxWidth: "350px" }}
        />
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Currently, the max-width for `TextField` seems not applying correctly. If I look at TextField with the inspect, it says `200px`

I know I can apply regular `width` like this.

```
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          key={e.id}
          value={e.message}
          label="Outlined"
          variant="outlined"
          multiline={true}
          style={{ width: "350px" }}
        />
```

But what I want here is `maxWidth`.

Ideally, I like to have the width of text input based on the message length which I pass to the `value` property like this `value={e.message}`.

So before the width hits `350px`, width needs to be kind of `auto` like the width is depends on the `message`, but once it hits `350px`, it will keep being `350px`.

Is that possible with the `TextField` component?

#### Attampts

I used `InputProps` proptery.

```
      {messages.map((e) => (
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          key={e.id}
          value={e.message}
          label="Outlined"
          variant="outlined"
          multiline={true}
          InputProps={{
            style: { maxWidth: "350px" }
          }}
        />
      ))}
```

But I got width `200px`.

Comment: You can wrap this element with div and style the div

Comment: @KonradLinkowski It seems like `maxWidth` is not applying even though I wrap the `TextField` with `div` and set `style={{ maxWidth: "350px" }}` to div tag.

Answer (score 0):

if you wrap in an div?

```
<div style: { width: "400px" }>
   <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          key={e.id}
          value={e.message}
          label="Outlined"
          variant="outlined"
          multiline={true}
          InputProps={{
            style: { maxWidth: "350px" }
          }}
        />
</div>
```

Comment: What I want to do here is to apply `maxWidth` so I wrap `TextField` with `div` and apply `style={{ maxWidth: "350px" }}` to div but it seems like not working the way I want